# Union queryset not giving expected result, Is it a Django ORM bug?

Tags: django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class PersonDetails(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    name= models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'person_details'


class Npr(models.Model):
    rid = models.AutoField(db_column='rid', primary_key=True)
    pid = models.ForeignKey(PersonDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='PID')
    rel = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    cid = models.ForeignKey(PersonDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='CID')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'npr'
        unique_together = (('pid', 'cid'),)
```

I built the following queryset:

```
idf = Npr.objects.select_related('cid').filter(pid = 198)
ids = Npr.objects.select_related('pid').filter(cid = 198)
all = ids.union(idf)
```

and the resulting SQL statement is:

```
(SELECT `npr`.`rid`, `npr`.`PID`, `npr`.`rel`, `npr`.`CID`, T3.`ID`, T3.`Name` FROM `npr` INNER JOIN `person_details` T3 ON (`npr`.`PID` = T3.`ID`) WHERE `npr`.`CID` = 198) 
    UNION
(SELECT `npr`.`rid`, `npr`.`PID`, `npr`.`rel`, `npr`.`CID`, T3.`ID`, T3.`Name` FROM `npr` INNER JOIN `person_details` T3 ON (`npr`.`CID` = T3.`ID`) WHERE `npr`.`PID` = 198)
```

my Npr data is:

```
+------+-----+-----+------+
| rid  | PID | rel | CID  |
+------+-----+-----+------+
| 40   | 198 | F   | 2111 |
| 42   | 198 | F   | 2110 |
| 1377 | 198 | F   | 1243 |
| 3305 | 198 | F   | 236  |
| 3379 | 198 | F   | 203  |
| 3384 | 198 | H   | 200  |
| 3388 | 213 | F   | 198  |
| 3389 | 218 | M   | 198  |
+------+-----+-----+------+
```

Now look at the following

```
>>> a0=all[0]
>>> a7=all[7]
>>> 
>>> a0.cid.id
198
>>> a0.pid.id
213
```

a0 returns the expected results but

```
>>> a7.cid.id
2111
>>> a7.pid.id
2111
```

a7 is not returning the expected results! the expected result is a7.pid.id=198. In addition; a0.cid.id sends the following SQL statement to database:

```
SELECT `person_details`.`ID`, `person_details`.`Name` FROM `person_details` WHERE `person_details`.`ID` = 198 LIMIT 21
```

but a0.pid.id doesn't.
Why the second part of the union queryset is not giving the correct results!?

Django Version: 3.0.4
Python version: 3.7.3
Database: 10.3.22-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately; I found a better way to get the same result using one queryset, that is using Q objects, the queryset will be:

```
all = Npr.objects.filter(Q(pid=198) | Q(cid=198))
```